# std_msgs::Duration multipliation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I want to calculate a distance. Therfore I have a std_msgs::Duration t and want to calculate:

```
d*d = t*t * w*w;
```

with w is the speed of sound (for now as a float).
The error I get is:

```
no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘const Time {aka const std_msgs::Time_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘const Time {aka const std_msgs::Time_<std::allocator<void> >}’)
 d1_2 = t1*t1*omega*omega;
```

I think I have to convert the duration into a float. But I don't know how to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244498/std_msgs::duration-multipliation/) by [eed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26667/eed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [API reference](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1DurationBase.html) for DurationBase, which Duration inherits from. You probably want `toSec` which returns a double.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2016-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26667/eed/) on 2016-09-27**:
That looks good but doesn't work:

```
error: ‘const Duration’ has no member named ‘toSec’
```

I used std_msgs::Duration. Now I try to ue ros::Duration, than i think your answer work.